# Reduce space between Label and value LWC lightning-input

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have the below lightning-input which I use to display some data in a component.  But the when I apply the below code, I am seeing more space between label and value. Is there anyway to reduce the space between them?

> 

```
        <div slot="body" class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-form_horizontal">
            <lightning-input type="text" label="Name:" value="ABC">
            </lightning-input>
        </div>
```

[image]
I tried to change the lightning-input to

> 

```
            <lightning-input type="text" class="slds-size_1-of-2" label="Name:" value="ABC">
            </lightning-input>
```

But I don't see much difference with it.

[image]

NOTE: Even I tried to add a custom label by hiding the default label from lightning-input. That also maintain the same space between label and value.

Is there anyway to reduce the space between label and Input field without decreasing the input field size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I can see in the inspector it seems that this is hard coded out of the box functionality coming from the css classes of your `<div slot="body" class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-form_horizontal">`.

[image]

**CSS for the label**

`flex-basis: calc(33% - 1.25rem);`

**CSS for the div container of the input**

`padding-left: 33%;`

That `33%` padding is what is causing the issue and that is coming down from the class of the wrapping `<div>` that you have in place.

**Solution**

1. What you can do to avoid this headache is try to tweak the classes of the parent `<div>` which currently are `class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-form_horizontal` and see if you can achieve what you want using slds styling.
2. If that doesn't work you can try to omit the label of the `<lightning-input>` and instead put your own label in place.

I put a playground for you with a workaround that can resolve your problem. Check it out [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/NjDsXghJU/2/edit).

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span>Name</span>
    <div class="input-wrapper">
        <lightning-input type="text" label=" " value="ABC"></lightning-input>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.wrapper > span {
    font-family: "Salesforce Sans",Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #3e3e3c;
    font-size: .75rem;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.input-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly with some css changes for me. Thanks @Arthlete

Comment: Glad I could help. :)